# Is the diy-vs-pro tag useful?

Tags: discussion

Currently there are [43 questions](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diy-vs-pro) with the [diy-vs-pro](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diy-vs-pro) tag.  Looking quickly through the list, I couldn't find any that were asking if they should do a job or hire a pro.  Is this tag useful in any way, or should it be removed?

Comment: Related IMO: https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/799/should-questions-asking-if-things-are-diy-be-on-topic

Comment: You guys need a [burninate-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info) tag

Answer (score -1):

I'd say leave it. While it doesn't enhance the tagged questions, it does have a clear usage excerpt, isn't confusing or ambiguous and it is a valid topic for the site ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191)). Just edit it out if it's inappropriate.

Comment: The trouble is, I'm not sure it's used appropriately anywhere.

Comment: It definitely isn't. It's an ironic thing that an otherwise on-topic tag isn't being used on-topic. But it's a "meh" thing. SO has hundreds of tags like this (some worse). We tend to leave them unless it's actively promoting confusion. [A recent failed burnination example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342959/should-we-burninate-chemistry)